# failed to build spingboot with swagger 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I am relatively new to spring. I tried to add API documentation with Swagger-2.0 and I no longer able to build

I failed to build with "gradlew build"

```
> getProductById FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginOrDefaultFor(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin)'
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginOrDefaultFor(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin)'

In build.gradle I added :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':api')
    implementation project(':util')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-spring-webflux:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}
```

Where should I look to find the root cause ?

Comment: what is getProducById ? (a junit i think). The issue appear with the junit or also with a bootrun ? And the problem only appear when you put swagger dependencies and it work without them ?

Comment: getProdutByID is a rest api . I work without swagger

@Test
 public void getProductById() {

        client.get()
            .uri("/product-composite/" + PRODUCT_ID_OK)
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectHeader().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.productId").isEqualTo(PRODUCT_ID_OK)
            .jsonPath("$.recommendations.length()").isEqualTo(1)
            .jsonPath("$.reviews.length()").isEqualTo(1);
 }